# How to copy a row n times in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

For a load test I have to copy a row in my table in a sqlite database 1000 (5000, 10000) times.
With the statement

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (                      
                          created,
                          modified,
                          anotherfield,
                          etc
                      )
                      SELECT created,
                          modified,
                          anotherfield,
                          etc FROM MYTABLE WHERE id = 1;
```

I can copy it one time. But it would be great to be able to put this into a loop to execute this statement n times.
It seems like SQLite does not support for-loops. I found something called `WITH RECURSIVE` which could be something like the SQLite way to handle loops. But if I execute

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(x) AS (VALUES(1) UNION ALL SELECT x+1 FROM cnt WHERE x<1000)
  <insert_statement_from_above>
```

the insert statement gets executed only once.
What am I doing wrong? How can I get to insert 1000 (5000, 10000) rows without having to add them all one by one? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must `CROSS` join the table to the recursive cte to produce 1000 rows:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte(x) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT x + 1 FROM cte WHERE x < 1000)
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (created, modified, anotherfield)
SELECT m.created, m.modified, m.anotherfield 
FROM MYTABLE m CROSS JOIN cte c 
WHERE m.id = 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7c424dfc930c311bbf98aae0045f9ba8) (for 3 rows).

Another way to use the recursive cte:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT created, modified, anotherfield, 1 x  
  FROM MYTABLE 
  WHERE id = 1
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT created, modified, anotherfield, x + 1 
  FROM cte 
  WHERE x < 1000
)
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (created, modified, anotherfield)
SELECT created, modified, anotherfield 
FROM cte;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=956f7674936cb390dc1b23a1154551f8).